# Did Abraham keep the sabbath?

Tags: law, sabbath

This concerns the position of the seventh day sabbath in world history from creation.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is off-topic as it does not ask about the interpretation of a specific Biblical passage.

Comment: I was JUST about to post an answer.  It is quite disappointing to see this.  There is no specific Bible text, which is why the question may not include one, but there ARE proper hermeneutics that can be applied to deduce the answer.

Comment: @curiousdannii "...hermeneutical methods cannot be applied when no text is referenced."  This statement is simply untrue.

Comment: By all means you can suggest improvements to the close reason message on Meta, but this type of question has never been on topic here.

Comment: This could be moved to Christianity.

Comment: Interesting question. You may better ask on https://judaism.stackexchange.com or https://christianity.stackexchange.com

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't be on-topic at Christianity.SE either. I don't know about the Judaism site.

Comment: @curiousdannii Check the dictionary definition of "hermeneutics."  You will find that the boiler-plate message used here does not agree with the dictionary.  The dictionary has it as "a method or theory of interpretation."  There is no such requirement for either a _method_ or for a _theory_ to have a _specific_ text to work with.  Working with simply the Hebrew/Aramaic/Greek _language_ could easily suffice, but in the case of this particular question there are many other Biblical passages that lead to the answer that YES, Abraham kept the Sabbath.

Comment: Maduoma, @Polyhat It will probably fit for Mi Yodeya https://judaism.stackexchange.com/ so polyhat can post his answer and maybe there will be good answers from Talmud or Midrashim